# FFMPEG format video with Laravel

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg

I have Laravel connects to FFMpeg to change video color space. I have a problem that when I change video color space using command line, the output video works pretty well but when I use Laravel, the output video is uglier than the video output from command line

Does anyone know to get the config of ffmpmeg when using cli and using Laravel to check the difference between them?

I have searched Google but I don't find a way to detect the difference config when using command line and using through Laravel

Answer (score -1):

You can use this `compatible` package for your `Laravel 10`

```
composer require pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg
```

this is the link of the [Package](https://packagist.org/packages/pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg)

Comment: I have used this too, but the result is like what I describe.